# How to know if my application admin or not

Tags: android, android-layout, service, broadcastreceiver, admin

I am creation app which make `my device as a admin` work **Great**.

But i want **trigger some message** when my `Application uninstall from device.`

1. when user `remove from admin`.
2. How to know if my `app Device admin is checked or not?`

I am using android inbuilt admin application demo.

**Please give me some idea.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will have to extend DeviceAdminReceiver and

```
public class DeviceAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(this, "admin_receiver_status_enabled");
        // admin rights
        App.getPreferences().edit().putBoolean(App.ADMIN_ENABLED, true).commit(); //App.getPreferences() returns the sharedPreferences

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return "admin_receiver_status_disable_warning";
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.info(this, "admin_receiver_status_disabled");
        // admin rights removed
        App.getPreferences().edit().putBoolean(App.ADMIN_ENABLED, false).commit(); //App.getPreferences() returns the sharedPreferences
    }
}
```

anywhere in your app:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdmin.class); 

if(mDPM != null &&mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
    // admin active
}
```

Comment: i am using this way.but when how to know in background my application admin is disable.

Comment: onDisabled will be called, even if your app is in background or not running at all. you could save the state in sharedPreferences

Comment: hey @malimo how to know my device admin when my app is not in running state.

Comment: i am sorry but i don't understand your problem. do you want to check if your app is device admin within another app?

Comment: no if my app is in background and user uninstall the app that time i want put one dialog with message.if ok press then admin is disable other wise not.

Comment: so you want to show a message (dialog) in case of an uninstallation while admin rights are enabled, because the uninstallation will fail in that case. sorry, i don't think that's possible... in my opinion android OS should handle that, i know it doesn't and that leads to confusion.

Comment: Need to call `getSystemService` on a Context